# how to handle laravel 5.4 database connection message

Tags: laravel-5.4

when my database connection wrong or my connection lost then get error like this

> QueryException in Connection.php line 647: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it.

How to handle this error in laravel 5.4

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, I think you need Try-Catch Block, and your Problem will be Solved, or you Need to be Clear about what Problem you are facing. Here is what you can try to solve your Problem.

```
try
{
    // Code that is Throwing Exception
}
catch(\QueryException $e)
{
    return redirect("some_page")->with("error","user friendly message");
}
```

Let me know if it helps or Let me know if you are looking for something else!

Comment: i need user friendly message when my database connection have an error  and where to write an error handling code in laravel because i set only environment variable for database connection

Comment: I've updated the answer @Divyesh, this is how you can show user friendly messages.